# Win32 How do I save a bitmap to a file

Tags: winapi, bitmap, save

I know this question might have been asked alot but I am having problems with it. Basically my program allows for you to paint on the screen using various pens. I have a case statement for save button all setup, I just don't know how to save a copy of what is painted on the window to My Documents.

Here's some of what I have at the moment:

```
RECT client;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &client);

int width = client.right - client.left;
int hight = client.bottom - client.top;

hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);

HDC backDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP backbuffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, hight);

Rectangle(backDC, client.left, client.top, client.right, client.bottom);

BitBlt(hdc, 0,0,width,hight, backDC, 0,0,SRCCOPY);

DeleteDC(backDC);
DeleteObject(backbuffer);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Win32: save .bmp image from HBITMAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586915/c-win32-save-bmp-image-from-hbitmap)